# Excel: Using COUNTIF + UNIQUE gives generic error "There's a prblem with this formula"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I'm trying to create an excel function that counts the number of unique entries in a range of (potentially merged) cells. The UNIQUE function returns two values for merged cell, one of which is zero. This seems easy enough, just count the cells that aren't equal to zero. However, all of the following formulas result in the generic "There's a problem with this formula" error:
`COUNTIF(UNIQUE(A2:P2,TRUE)<>0,TRUE)`
`COUNTIF(UNIQUE(A2:P2,TRUE),"<>0")`
`COUNTIF(NOT(UNIQUE(A2:P2,TRUE)=0),TRUE)`

What's especially infuriating is that if I put the first argument of `COUNTIF` in another cell (say `R2`), and refer to the spill range (i.e. `COUNTIF(R2#,TRUE)`), all 3 of those formulas work fine. What on earth is happening here?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the error its natural phenomenon of any `IFs` family function, as per the `COUNTIFS()` or `COUNTIF()` function that first criteria states to take `range` and not `array` here, `UNIQUE()` is returning an array. Try using `SUM()` function

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the error its **natural phenomenon** of any `IFs family` functions, as per the `COUNTIFS()` or `COUNTIF()` function that **first criteria/parameter** states to take `range` and not `array` here, `UNIQUE()` is `returning an array`. Try using `SUM()` function.

`COUNTIF()` syntax as per `MSFT` Documentations: **[Read Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)**

[image]

---

Instead use `SUM()` as below:

```
=SUM(N(UNIQUE(A2:P2,TRUE)<>0))
```

---

Or,

```
=SUM(--(UNIQUE(A2:P2,1)<>0))
```

---

in place `N()` one can also use double unary `--`

---

Or to exclude the blanks before using `UNIQUE()` one can use `TOROW()`

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(TOROW(A2:P2,3),1))
```

---

In the `MSFT` documentation it mentions the first criteria ***Range*** can contain **arrays** which means an array can be used as a range when placed in a different column or as in helper columns which can be referenced, it doesn't say it can be used within the function directly, there is a difference in it, to explain, here is a .gif

[image]

---

Comment: Wow the documentation is misleading. "***Range*** can contain numbers __arrays__, a named range, or references that contain numbers"  
Thank you for the suggestions. I ended up going with the first solution I could get to work, which was `=LET(foo,UNIQUE(A32:P32,TRUE)<>0,COUNTA(FILTER(foo,foo)))`

Comment: @pkujawa no its not like that. Its referring to an array which is returned using `INDEX()` or `XLOOKUP()` specifically, let me show you a `.gif`. Also I have not suggested using `LET()` or `FILTER()` it unnecessarily iterates few more extra functions. The one i have suggested will be faster and efficient more that the one you are trying to use.

Comment: I understand now. There's also an error in my solution above: if all values in the range are unique, it returns 1 less than it should. I will use `=COUNTA(UNIQUE(TOROW(A2:I2,3),1))` instead :)

Comment: Be aware that `TOROW(range,3)` can be unreliable in case the range contains calculation results from formulas. They may be excluded from the result when they recalculate. (More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77563158/12634230 )

Comment: Then this should be the right way to reach `=SUM(--(UNIQUE(A2:P2,1)<>0))` at goal!

Comment: Nice one @MayukhBhattacharya and `=SUM(N(UNIQUE(A2:P2,1)<>""))` for alphanumeric.